# How to set the title of a button in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

In the CK Editor I wish to show the corresponding shortcut buttons when the user hovers over the appropriate button.

For example when I hover over "B" it says "Bold", but I want it to say "Bold Ctrl+B". This is similar to MS Word and even Stack Overflow's editor. How can I do this?

The idea I had was to make changes to the button text after the editor has loaded.

For example like this:

```
// Invalid Code - Just an example
editor.setButtonText('codeSnippet', config.lang.codesnippet.title + " - Ctrl + K"));
```

Of course the above is invalid code as I am unsure how to set the button text.

**Update**

I now know how to retrieve the button text for a button. i.e.

```
config.lang.codesnippet.title
```

But I am unable to set the value for the title.

Comment: There is actually a ticket for this feature on the CKEditor tracker: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10015. You can follow it to see when this gets implemented. It's scheduled for CKEditor 4.6 right now.

Comment: It's currently under review. Hopefully will make it in the CKEditor 4.6 release

Comment: If a ticket is under review does it mean it might not make the release.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but others might have the same problem, here's the hack-around I've found: you can manually override the `title` attribute of the buttons.

CKEditor references toolbar buttons by classes. The "Bold" button has the following class(es): `cke_button cke_button__bold cke_button_off`

All you need to do is to get a reference for the HTML element ( `getElementsByClass()` in plain JavaScript ) and change the `title` attribute using `.setAttribute()`

My project is in Angular2 so in my case it looks like this:
`this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.cke_button.cke_button__bold').setAttribute('title', 'Bold (Ctrl+B)');`

In plain JS it would look something like:
`document.getElementsByClass('.cke_button.cke_button__bold')[0].setAttribute('title', 'Bold (Ctrl+B)');`

Here is a list (not comprehensive) for some of the buttons:

Bold:`cke_button cke_button__bold cke_button_off`

Italic:`cke_button cke_button__italic cke_button_off`

Underline:`cke_button cke_button__underline cke_button_off`

Bulleted List:`cke_button cke_button__bulletedlist cke_button_off`

Numbered list:`cke_button cke_button__numberedlist cke_button_off`

...and so on.